# Style Issues in IE 10 Standard Mode

Tags: css, internet-explorer

when i open my application in IE 10 "quirks" Mode, pages styles works fine, but when i change it to "Standards" Mode using F12(devTools) page alignment is  not working as expected.

to set height and width i m using Percentage(%) , here i m setting height 100% is not getting effected in IE 10 "Standards" . please suggest me why styles are not working in IE 10 "Standards" Mode where is everything is working fine in IE 10 "Quirks" Mode.

Comment: Pls show some of your code.

Comment: The height of what? Please eleborate your question. and include the relevant CSS and HTML to the post.

Comment: Well sounds like your HTML and CSS is not standards base. But since you did not post actual code, it is impossible to tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

IE10 quirks mode is an [interoperable quirks mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869300(v=vs.85).aspx) (IQM) that aligns to the quirks mode defined by the HTML5 standard (and, by extension, to the quirks mode behavior of other major browsers).  (For IE9 and earlier, quirks mode emulated IE5 behavior.)  As a result, IQM picks up various changes to CSS parsing/rendering made to IE since IE6.  This includes box model changes, different default values, inheritance changes, and so on.

As noted elsewhere, there's no comprehensive list to these changes.  But there are a few things on MSDN that might help:

- The [CSS Compat by Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508(v=vs.85).aspx) page provides a high level comparison of CSS changes from Ie6 through IE10.
- The [Compat Cookbook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn384059(vs.85)) discusses some [big changes from IE9 through IE11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn467849(v=vs.85).aspx) and provides links that  [summarize minor changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn467846(v=vs.85).aspx#minor_changes_in_recent_versions_of_internet_explorer) for the same versions of the browser.
- The [Dev Guides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg125382) describe changes to IE11 and link to similar information about changes to other versions, going back to IE7.

So it's possible that documentation exists for the specific set of changes you've run into.  Hard to say without actually seeing the code in question.

If your code works for the older quirks (IE5) mode, you can trigger that in IE10/IE11 by adding an `x-ua-compatible` token to your page (or serving one from the web server.  Set `content` to `"IE=5"` and you may be back in business.  (See that first link for details.)

Note that if the x-ua-compatible token helps, you should consider that a temporary measure and take time to redesign the page to use standards mode (or edge mode, as it's now called).  [Document modes have been deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn384051(v=vs.85).aspx) and the IE team has been clear they intend to move away from them.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

P.S.  For better results and more direct answers, it helps to isolate things into a small, reproducible case and then post that.  Others can see the results as you see them and then use their expertise to troubleshoot things.